# Java MouseListener not working on JApplet

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, japplet, event-dispatch-thread

I have this tetris game but the mouselistener is not working. It's supposed to change a boolean's value to true when the button are pressed.

### TetrisApplet

```
public class TetrisApplet extends JApplet implements MouseListener{

    public boolean moveLeft=false;
    public boolean moveRight=false;
    public boolean moveDown=false;
    public boolean rotate=false;

    JLabel show_score;
    int score = 0;

    public void init(){

        TetrisView tv = new TetrisView();
        setSize(200, 420);
        add(tv);
        Frame f = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();
        f.setTitle("Vasileios Toumpelis - 1401907");
        show_score = new JLabel("Score: "+ score);
        add(show_score, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);

        addMouseListener(this);
        tv.addMouseListener(this);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {

        }


        tv.addBlock();
        tv.game_going=true;
        while (tv.game_going) {
            tv.addBlock();
            tv.checkRowCompletion();
        }

        tv.printGameOver();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) // left click
        {
            moveLeft = true;
        }
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) // right click
        {
            moveRight = true;
        }
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) // scroll
        {
            rotate = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }


}
```

### TetrisView

```
public class TetrisView extends JPanel{

    /*public void init()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200,420));
        this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }*/

    static Color[] colors = {green, blue, red, yellow, magenta, pink, cyan};
    int[][] gameGrid = new int[10][20];
    static int size = 20;
    boolean game_going =true;
    //Block block = new Block();
    TetrisApplet ap = new TetrisApplet();

    //draws a square and occupies the space in gameGrid to keep track of the coordinates
    public void drawSquare(int x, int y){
        gameGrid[x][y] = 1;
    }
    //draws a tris object by using 4 squares with specific coordinates specigied in the block type Arrays
    public void drawBlock(int x, int y ,int[] XArray, int[] YArray){
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
            drawSquare(x + XArray[i], y + YArray[i]);
        }
    }

    //erases a square from the gameGrid
    public void eraseSquare(int x, int y){
        gameGrid[x][y] = 0;
    }
    //erases a block by erasing the its' four squares
    public void eraseBlock(int x, int y ,int[] XArray, int[] YArray){
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
            eraseSquare(x + XArray[i], y + YArray[i]);
        }
    }

    //override paint component to display all the elements
    public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g)
    {

        super.paint(g);

        for (int x=0;x<10;x++)
            for (int y=0;y<20;y++)
                //checks if the specific space of the gameGrid is occupied
                if (gameGrid[x][y]==1)
                {
                    //if it is occupies it draws the element
                    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    g.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
                    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    g.fill3DRect(x * size + 1, y * size + 1, size, size, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if its not occupied it fill a blank space (erases elements)
                    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    g.fillRect(x * size, y * size, size, size);
                }
    }

    //prevents the tetris blocks from escaping the games border (10x20)
    public boolean isInBorders(int x,int y, int shape, int rotation)
    {
        int[] XArray = Block.ArrayX[shape][rotation];
        int[] YArray = Block.ArrayY[shape][rotation];

        // loop over the four squares of the current shape
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            int xCell = x+XArray[i];
            int yCell = y+YArray[i];

            // gameGrid border check
            if (xCell<0) return false;
            if (xCell>=10) return false;
            if (yCell<0) return false;
            if (yCell>=20) return false;

            // checks if its occupied
            if (gameGrid[xCell][yCell]==1) return false;
        }
        //returns true when the space is available
        return true;
    }

    public void addBlock()
    {
        int x=5,y=0;
        int shape, rotation;

        shape = (int) (7*Math.random());
        rotation = (int) (4*Math.random());

        int[] XArray = Block.ArrayX[shape][rotation];
        int[] YArray = Block.ArrayY[shape][rotation];

        if (!isInBorders(x, y, shape, rotation))
        {
            game_going=false;
            drawBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);
            repaint();
            return;
        }

        drawBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);
        repaint();

        int delay=100;  // mini second
        int frame=0;
        boolean reachFloor=false;
        while (!reachFloor)
        {
            try { Thread.sleep(delay); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
            eraseBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);

            // add mouse control
            if (ap.moveLeft && isInBorders(x - 1, y, shape, rotation)) {
                x -= 1;
                System.out.println(ap.moveLeft);
            }
            if (ap.moveRight && isInBorders(x + 1, y, shape, rotation)) {
                x += 1;
                System.out.println(ap.moveRight);
            }
            if (ap.moveDown && isInBorders(x, y + 1, shape, rotation)) {
                y += 1;
            }
            if (ap.rotate && isInBorders(x, y, shape, (rotation + 1) % 4))
            {
                rotation = (rotation+1)%4;
                XArray = Block.ArrayX[shape][rotation];
                YArray = Block.ArrayY[shape][rotation];
                ap.rotate=false;
            }

            if (frame % 5==0) y += 1;  // fall for every 30 frame
            if (!isInBorders(x, y, shape, rotation)) // reached floor
            {
                reachFloor=true;
                y -= 1;  // restore position
            }
            drawBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);
            repaint();
            frame++;
        }

    }

    //clear a row if it is full
    public void clearCompleteRow(int[] completed) {
        // erase
        for (int i = 0; i < completed.length; i++) {
            if (completed[i] == 1) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    gameGrid[x][i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }

    //shifts down the row above the cleared one
    public void shiftDown(int[] completed)
    {
        for (int row=0;row<completed.length;row++)
        {
            if (completed[row]==1)
            {
                for (int y=row;y>=1;y--)
                {
                    for (int x=0;x<10;x++)
                    {
                        gameGrid[x][y] = gameGrid[x][y-1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void checkRowCompletion()
    {
        int[] complete = new int[20];
        for (int y=0;y<20;y++)  // 20 rows
        {
            int filledCell = 0;
            for (int x=0;x<10;x++)  // 10 columns
            {
                if (gameGrid[x][y]==1) filledCell++;
                if (filledCell==10) // row completed
                {
                    complete[y]=1;
                }
            }
        }

        clearCompleteRow(complete);
        shiftDown(complete);

    }

    public void printGameOver()
    {
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
        //ap.show_score.setText("Game Over!!!");
        //repaint();
    }



}
```

### Block

```
public class Block {

    /*creates two arrays with the coordinates (x,y) of each type of tetris blocks. The first element
    in the row is the default shape and the next three are the rotation positions of the blocks*/
    static int[][][] ArrayX = {
            { {0,0,1,2}, {0,0,0,1}, {2,0,1,2}, {0,1,1,1} },  // shape 0
            { {0,0,1,1}, {1,2,0,1}, {0,0,1,1}, {1,2,0,1} },  // shape 1
            { {1,1,0,0}, {0,1,1,2}, {1,1,0,0}, {0,1,1,2} },  // shape 2
            { {0,1,2,2}, {0,1,0,0}, {0,0,1,2}, {1,1,0,1} },  // shape 3
            { {1,0,1,2}, {1,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,2}, {0,0,1,0} },  // shape 4
            { {0,1,0,1}, {0,1,0,1}, {0,1,0,1}, {0,1,0,1} },  // shape 5
            { {0,1,2,3}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3}, {0,0,0,0} }   // shape 6
    };

    static int[][][] ArrayY = {
            { {0,1,0,0}, {0,1,2,2}, {0,1,1,1}, {0,0,1,2} },  // shape 0
            { {0,1,1,2}, {0,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,2}, {0,0,1,1} },  // shape 1
            { {0,1,1,2}, {0,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,2}, {0,0,1,1} },  // shape 2
            { {0,0,0,1}, {0,0,1,2}, {0,1,1,1}, {0,1,2,2} },  // shape 3
            { {0,1,1,1}, {0,1,1,2}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,1,1,2} },  // shape 4
            { {0,0,1,1}, {0,0,1,1}, {0,0,1,1}, {0,0,1,1} },  // shape 5
            { {0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3}, {0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3} }   // shape 6
    };



}
```

I tried to do this but still confused:

```
public void addBlock()
{
    int delay = 1000;
    ActionListener fall = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int x=5,y=0;
            int shape, rotation;

            shape = (int) (7*Math.random());
            rotation = (int) (4*Math.random());

            int[] XArray = Block.ArrayX[shape][rotation];
            int[] YArray = Block.ArrayY[shape][rotation];

            if (!isInBorders(x, y, shape, rotation))
            {
                game_going=false;
                drawBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);
                repaint();
                return;
            }

            drawBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);
            repaint();


            int frame=0;
            boolean reachFloor=false;

            while (!reachFloor)
            {
                eraseBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);

                // add mouse control
                if (ap.moveLeft && isInBorders(x - 1, y, shape, rotation)) {
                    x -= 1;
                    System.out.println(ap.moveLeft);
                }
                if (ap.moveRight && isInBorders(x + 1, y, shape, rotation)) {
                    x += 1;
                    System.out.println(ap.moveRight);
                }
                if (ap.moveDown && isInBorders(x, y + 1, shape, rotation)) {
                    y += 1;
                }
                if (ap.rotate && isInBorders(x, y, shape, (rotation + 1) % 4))
                {
                    rotation = (rotation+1)%4;
                    XArray = Block.ArrayX[shape][rotation];
                    YArray = Block.ArrayY[shape][rotation];
                    ap.rotate=false;
                }

                if (frame % 5==0) y += 1;  // fall for every 30 frame
                if (!isInBorders(x, y, shape, rotation)) // reached floor
                {
                    reachFloor=true;
                    y -= 1;  // restore position
                }

                drawBlock(x, y, XArray, YArray);
                repaint();
                frame++;

            }

        }
    };
    new javax.swing.Timer(delay, fall).start();

}
```

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: The first problem with the above code is that it is blocking the EDT with the game loop logic.  Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.  (A Swing `Timer` to trigger each game state change).

Comment: Im using an applet because the teacher asked us to.

Comment: Also, the game runs and the blocks are falling but I cant controll them

Comment: *"..because the teacher asked us to.."*  Well, like I said, please refer them to that blog article.  They should avoid applets..

Comment: *"Also, the game runs and the blocks are falling"* Yes, I saw that. *"..but I cant controll them"*  You already said that.  I thought when making the 2nd comment (about the 1st problem) *"Meh.. I'll check it again after the EDT problem is fixed.."*.  Back to you.

Comment: I changed my addBlock method to use a swing timer but i still dont get the result i want. swing timers confuse me.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).